# two equivalent projections in matrix algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra and $a$ be a positive element in $A$ such that $\|a\|\leq 1$,show that

$p =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    a & (a-a^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
    (a-a^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}   & 1-a\\
   \end{matrix} \right ]$

is equivalent to 
$q =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
   \end{matrix} \right ].$

My thought :I want to prove that $\|p-q\|<1$,then $p$ is homotopic to $q$ and so $p$ is equivalent to $q$.But I can not show that $\|p-q\|\neq 1$.

Comment: May the following be helpful: Based on the path $t\mapsto ta$, consider
$p_t = \begin{bmatrix}
ta & \big(ta-t^2a^2)^{1/2} \\
    \big(ta-(ta)^2\big)^{1/2}   & 1-ta\end{bmatrix}$.
Then $p_1=p$ and $p_0 =\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to show that $\|p-q\|<1$ won't work, for if $a=0$, we have 
$p=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$, and $\|p-q\|=1$.

Instead, try showing that that the path of projections $(p_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ given by
$$p_t=\begin{bmatrix}
t+(1-t)a&((t+(1-t)a)-(t+(1-t)a)^2)^\frac12\\
((t+(1-t)a)-(t+(1-t)a)^2)^\frac12 &t(1-a)
\end{bmatrix}$$
is continuous, for then you have $p\sim_h q$.  To show that this path of projections is continuous, it suffices to show that each matrix coefficient is continuous.  The only not entirely trivial part of this is showing that the off-diagonal entries are continuous, but this follows from the fact that $t+(1-t)a$ lies in $C^*(1,a)$, is positive, and $\sigma(t+(1-t)a)\subset[0,1]$ for each $t\in[0,1]$.

Comment: You mentioned that $t+(1-t)a$ is positive,then we can use functional calculus to show that off diagonal entries are continuous?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: If two projections are equivalent in $M_n(A)$,then they have the same trace,I wonder whether the converse is 
also correct.